# Passing local variable to remote shell bash script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, local-variables, remote-host

Trying to pass local variable to remote shell using bash script. Here is what I am trying. This is test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

envi=$1

function samplefunction {
                        echo "Environment selected is $envi"
                        }

if [ "$envi" = "test" ]; then
   ssh user@remotehost <<EOF
   $(typeset -f samplefunction)
   samplefunction
EOF

else
 echo "Please pass correct parameter which is - test"
fi
```

When I try to execute "./test.sh test" the result I am getting is "Environment selected is". shell is not able to pass the variable to the remote system.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` does not (and can't) make such variables available on the remote side.

You can instead embed the definition just like you embedded your function:

```
ssh user@remotehost <<EOF
   $(declare -p envi)
   $(typeset -f samplefunction)
   samplefunction
EOF
```

You can also copy all known variables. In that case it helps to squash the errors about setting read-only values:

```
ssh user@remotehost <<EOF
   {
     $(declare -p)
   } 2> /dev/null
   $(typeset -f samplefunction)
   samplefunction
EOF
```

If you have a specific variable you frequently want to copy, you can choose to have `ssh` send it automatically by adding `SendEnv envi` to your ssh config. The variable must be exported for this to work.

Comment: Even after declaring inside the ssh, it is not able to read the variable. ssh user@remotehost <<EOF
   $(declare -p envi)
   $(typeset -f samplefunction)
   samplefunction
EOF

Comment: how about using EOT instead?

Comment: The delimiter token is arbitrary. You can choose any word of any length and capitalization.